# Tomcat 7 / 8 and IBM JRE won't initialize DSA key

Tags: java, tomcat, https, aix

I'm reproducing a problem reported by one of our customers.

He has a Tomcat 7 running on AIX 7.1 with IBM JRE 7.

The Tomcat has a HTTPS connector defined:

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.key" keystorePass="password"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

The keystore contains a 1024 bits DSA keypair.

When a HTTPS request comes in the DSA key won't be initialized, which results in a handshake failure.
Output from catalina.out with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_EC
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain RSA
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_EC
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_RSA
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
```

If I switch to IBM JRE 8 the key get's initialized:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_EC
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain RSA
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_EC
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain EC_RSA
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain RSA
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias null
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain DSA
matching alias: mykey
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseServerAlias mykey
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, return true
JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator DiffieHellman from provider TBD via init
DHCrypt:  DH KeyPairGenerator  from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

Our customer stated that the same keystore worked in Tomcat 6 and with the same JRE 7.

I did some tests with the original keystore in the following environment:

**AIX**

```
oslevel -s
7100-04-04-1717
```

**Java**

```
Java7 - IBM JRE - java7_64_SR3 (also SR10_FP1)
Java8 - IBM JRE - java8_64_SR3_FP22
```

**Tomcat**

```
apache-tomcat-6.0.36
apache-tomcat-7.0.69
apache-tomcat-8.5.16
```

The results are:

**Working:**

Tomcat 6 + Java 7

Tomcat 6 + Java 8

Tomcat 7 + Java 8

Tomcat 8 + Java 8

**Not working:**

Tomcat 7 + Java 7

Tomcat 8 + Java 7

It seems to be some issue which occours when running Tomcat 7 / 8 with IMB JRE 7, but not in other combinations.

The JREs have been installed only for reproducing this problem.

I really can't find the reason why it's not working in those combinations.

Any ideas what could be the reason or what I could try?

*EDIT*: Simply using JRE 8 is not possible due to other limitations.
We got a workaround by providing a keystore with 2048 bits RSA keys which works with all combinations. It still is really unsatisfying not to know what's the problem with the original keystore.

Comment: Guess you(r client) should always use Java8.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible due to other limitations. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like `DSA` doesn't get initialized with your IBM Java 7 setup. Weird.

Comment: There aren't too many differences between Tomcat 6/7/8 when it comes to connector and TLS code. Mostly just the defaults (protocols, cipher suites) which have changed. For example, recent versions of Tomcat 7/8/9 all have `SSLv3` disabled, but it can be re-enabled if necessary. Tomcat 8.5 and 9 have many changes relative to the others in terms of how TLS is configured, but the TLS handshake is still being performed by the same component(s) in all cases (e.g. OpenSSL or JSSE). Presumably, OpenSSL isn't in play, here.